# storageRef.child is not a function in firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage, gatsby

Having issues uploading files to Firebase using the **[react-firebase-file-uploader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-firebase-file-uploader)** package.

The error received is `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: storageRef.child is not a function`

Firstly, `firebase` is imported into my GatsbyJS `Layout.js` in `componentDidMount` as

**Layout.js**

```
componentDidMount() {
  const app = import('firebase/app');
  const auth = import('firebase/auth');
  const database = import('firebase/firestore');
  const storage = import('firebase/storage');

  Promise.all([app, auth, database, storage]).then(values => {
    const firebase = getFirebase(values[0]);
    !this.isCancelled && this.setState({ firebase });
  });
}
```

Then, `firebase` is added as `props` using `React.createContext` to pass `functions` to components as

**FirebaseContext.js**

```
const FirebaseContext = React.createContext(null);
export const withFirebase = Component => props => (
  <FirebaseContext.Consumer>
    {firebase => <Component {...props} firebase={firebase} />}
  </FirebaseContext.Consumer>
);

export default FirebaseContext;
```

Inside the `firebase` component, we use `onboardStorage` as a function containing `this.storage` as

**Firebase.js**

```
class Firebase {
  constructor(app) {
    app.initializeApp(config);

    /* Firebase APIs */
    this.app = app;
    this.storage = app.storage();

  // *** Storage API ***
  onboardStorage = () => this.storage;
}

let firebase;

function getFirebase(app, auth, database, storage) {
  if (!firebase) {
    firebase = new Firebase(app, auth, database, storage);
  }

  return firebase;
}

export default getFirebase;
```

Which is then passed to the `FileUploader` component in my form component as

**Form.js**

```
<FileUploader
  accept="image/*"
  name="avatar"
  filename="operator_accreditation"
  storageRef={() => firebase.onboardStorage().ref(`${uid}/files`)}
  onUploadStart={this.handleUploadStart}
  onUploadError={this.handleUploadError}
  onUploadSuccess={this.handleUploadSuccess}
  onProgress={this.handleProgress}
/>
```

each of the handle functions in **Form.js** are as follows

```
    handleUploadStart = () =>
    this.setState({
      operatorAccreditationIsUploading: true,
      operatorAccreditationProgress: 0
    });

  handleProgress = operatorAccreditationProgress =>
    this.setState({ operatorAccreditationProgress });

  handleUploadError = error => {
    this.setState({ operatorAccreditationIsUploading: false });
    console.error(error);
  };

  handleUploadSuccess = filename => {
    const { firebase, uid } = this.props;
    this.setState({
      operatorAccreditation: filename,
      operatorAccreditationProgress: 100,
      operatorAccreditationIsUploading: false
    });
    const storageOperatorAccreditation = firebase.onboardStorage();
    storageOperatorAccreditation
      .ref(`${uid}/files`)
      .child(filename)
      .getDownloadURL()
      .then(url => this.setState({ operatorAccreditation: url }));
  };
```

`const uid` is the the `auth.uid`

Adding a `console` message indicates that none are triggered on uploading a file.

The error occurs after a file is selected, indicating that the issue is at the `storageRef` of the `FileUploader`.  What have I done wrong to get `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: storageRef.child is not a function`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had a similar issue. The problem is that you pass a function as storageRef property to your FileUploader. Instead you should pass a storageRef object directly like this:

```
<FileUploader
  accept="image/*"
  name="avatar"
  filename="operator_accreditation"
  storageRef={firebase.onboardStorage().ref(`${uid}/files`)}
  onUploadStart={this.handleUploadStart}
  onUploadError={this.handleUploadError}
  onUploadSuccess={this.handleUploadSuccess}
  onProgress={this.handleProgress}
/>
```